# Laravel: Switch between created_at and updated_at

Tags: laravel

I have a post with comments and display the created time of the commment. Also I added posibility to update the comment and now I need to display the updated time in my blade. Any ideas how I can do this? How can I switch between created_at and updated_at?
Thx

Comment: `$model->updated_at`... You don't need to "switch" between them; just display `updated_at`. When the model is created (first saved to the database), `created_at` and `updated_at` are the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table should have `$table->timestamps();` in your `database/migration/bla_bla_table.php`

If you have this just open your blade file, find the created_at on your comment section and change it as updated_at.